# Detectar abertura de PopUp de impressão ou um Dowload

Tags: javascript, download, impressão

eu queria saber se alguém conhece alguma forma de detectar a abertura daquela popup padrão de impressão para a execução de um javascript.

**Meu problema:** 
Eu precisava executar um script quando o usuário fizesse o download ou imprimisse um PDF que está sendo exibido para ele da seguinte forma dentro da minha página:

[image: Esse é aquele visualizador padrão do navegador]

Ele teria que utilizar essas duas opções padrões do visualizador embebbed.
Alguém sabe como eu capturaria esses eventos com javascript? 
(Lembrando que o código do visualizador é externo, não consegui capturar os ids do botão).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christian confesso que não entendi muito bem o que deseja fazer, mas, deixei um exemplo para você ver como pode realizar uma ação antes de imprimir utilizando o método nativo javascript **onbeforeprint**:

```js
function Antes() {
  window.onbeforeprint = function() {
     alert('Antes de imprimir!')
  }
}

function Imprimir() { 
  window.print()
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Antes();Imprimir()">Imprimir</button>
```

Comment: Até que não, quase isso mais não consigo colocar um "onclick" no botão imprimir de visualizador padrão dos navegadores...